# How can I access more than 251GB in a Docker named volume in WSL2?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, sql-server-linux

I've created a named volume for my SQL Linux data files but the default size of 251G was too small.
I followed the instructions to [expand the size of a WSL2 VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#expanding-the-size-of-your-wsl-2-virtual-hard-disk) and then use `resize2fs` to increase to about 900GB.

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb 900000M
```

Using `df -Th` I can see the increased size of 865GB, which is great. But the devices with the docker mounts still show the old size of 251GB.

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       ext4      865G  1.2G  826G   1% /
tools          9p        3.8T  250G  3.5T   7% /init
none           devtmpfs   13G     0   13G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      13G     0   13G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           tmpfs      13G   12K   13G   1% /run
none           tmpfs      13G     0   13G   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      13G     0   13G   0% /run/shm
none           tmpfs      13G     0   13G   0% /run/user
tmpfs          tmpfs      13G  399M   13G   4% /mnt/wsl
C:\            9p        3.8T  250G  3.5T   7% /mnt/c
G:\            9p        3.8T  428G  3.4T  12% /mnt/g
/dev/sdd       ext4      251G  2.8G  236G   2% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache
none           tmpfs      13G   12K   13G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/shared-sockets/host-services
/dev/sdc       ext4      251G  126M  239G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy
/dev/loop0     iso9660   384M  384M     0 100% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools
```

I can't resize `/dev/sdd` or `/dev/sdc` - I get the following result:

```
The containing partition (or device) is only 67108864 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 74240000 blocks.
```

I have tried restarting Docker and recreating the named volumes.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? How I can increase the space available for the named volumes or get docker to use all of the available space?

Comment: Did you tried to recreate the named volume?

Comment: Yes I did. I'll update the question to be more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the same instructions as in [expand the size of a WSL2 VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/vhd-size), only instead of doing steps 2. and 3. use `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Docker\wsl\data\<disk>.vhdx` as `<pathToVHD>` in further steps, where `<disk>.vhdx` is most likely `ext4.vhdx` and full path is most likely `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx`.

Also, in step 6. be sure to use Docker partition in `resize2fs` command instead of wsl2 partition. In your opening post the Docker one would be `/dev/sdd` instead of wsl2 `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: Can confirm this worked on Windows 11 with a Ubuntu WSL2 install. After I followed the vanilla Microsoft guide I was still running into problems with Docker running out of space and had a suspicion what I did changed nothing. This answer confirmed that and after following your steps I'm now able to build my Docker images successfully.

Comment: Also, the guide referenced above has been moved. It can be found under `Expand the size of your WSL 2 Virtual Hard Disk`  by clicking on the link above or directly here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/vhd-size